# Реализация программы на Си

Tags: c

Цель:

1)пользователь вводит слова(англ)

2)программа находит самое длинное слово через strlen

3)выводит на экран строчку без самого длинного слова

Проблема:

Реализация ввода слов из клавиатуры

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    char word[4][40] = { "doko","mobus","jok","\0" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        printf(" %s", word[i]);
        if (a < strlen(word[i]))
        {
            a = strlen(word[i]);
            b = i;
        }
        //printf(" %d", a);
    }
    printf(" \nmax length of word %d", a);
    printf(" \nnumber of word %d", b + 1);
    printf("\n");
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) //вывод цыкла без самого длинного слова
    {
        if (c != b)
        {
            printf(" %s", word[c]);
        }
        else
        {
            c++;
            printf(" %s", word[c]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Вводите строку, а её уже разбиваете на массив слов.

Comment: При вводе вы вместо `scanf("%s", word[i])` зачем-то напиcали printf...

Comment: То вывод масива слов

Comment: Погуглил команды для работы со строками,нашел способ поделить строку на слова(юзая команду strtok) но загнать значения слов в масив для последующей обработки не получается